# how to apply text watermark to text box in xaml (windows 8 metrro app)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am workng on windows 8 app getting problem to use text watermark to text box, can anybody help me to find out how we can apply water mark init .

below is the code of  my text box.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtUserName" Width="351" Height="45" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" Background="{x:Null}"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
<TextBox Width="250" Name="_txtBox" PlaceholderText="Please enter CS#"/>
```

[image]

Comment: In UWP xaml, I implement your solution and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use Callisto toolkit for windows 8 it has watermark textbox control. you can install it from nuget package manager.
use this namespace in your page..

```
xmlns:CallistoControls="using:Callisto.Controls"
```

use the control like this.

```
 <CallistoControls:WatermarkTextBox Watermark="Type to message"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" MaxHeight="100"    Padding="5,5,20,30" />
```

there are other useful controls too. hope this helps you

Comment: If you're targeting 8.1 then the default TextBox control includes watermark (I believe it's called PlaceholderText).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it without using a third-party library or overriding the text box and creating your own "Watermark Text Box" class. You just listen for the got/lost focus events and display your text appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on 3rd party SDKs, you can create your own. Check out these tutorials.

[Create Your First WinRT WatermarkTextBox Control](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/blagunas/archive/2012/03/06/create-your-first-winrt-watermarktextbox-control.aspx)

[Watermark TextBox in Windows Store apps](http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=297)

[WaterMarkTextbox Control in Windows Store Application Using XAML](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5439e6/watermarktextbox-control-in-windows-store-application-using/)